# Regex that is working in C# is not working in MSBuild

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I want to verify that the version being used when packing some nuget-packages using `dotnet build /p:VERSION=1.2.3` and `GeneratePackageOnBuild`. My regex expressen is working in LINQPad 6 using C#:

```cs
Regex.Match("1.2.3", @"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,6}(-(beta|rc)(\d{1,1})?)?$")
```

However in my `default.props` that is being imported by all csproj-files (which are using the new sdk-style, if that is relevant) I have this and it is not working at all:

```xml
<Target Name="ValidateVersion" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionRegex>^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,6}(-(beta|rc)(\d{1,1})?)?$</VersionRegex>
    <VersionTest>1.2.3</VersionTest> <!-- Just to make it easier during testing -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Error
    Text="Version is not following the correct format: $(VersionRegex)"
    Condition=" $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(VersionTest)', `$(VersionRegex)`)) " />
</Target>
```

It does not matter if I inline `VersionRegex` and `VersionTest`, it is still not working. Any ideas why it is working in C# but not in MSBuild?

Comment: I got nothing on this System (only here because of the C# tag), but usually types have to be properly anotated. And those do not look like they are notated properly as string. How ho the text and condition strings below are anotated.

Comment: could be that it's not coming across as expected with xml escaping.   try sticking your regex inside a CDATA.

Comment: @viethoang: there are only 5 characters that need to be escaped/encoded in XML: `<`, `>`, `&` and both single-quote (/apostrophe) and double-quote. I don't see any of those

Comment: True, next thought is to replace the four single quotes inside IsMatch() with &quot;

Comment: @Christopher Sounds plausible. How do I annotate them as strings? I tried to inline the variable as `[System.String]'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,6}(-(beta|rc)(\d{1,1})?)?$'` and with back ticks but I still get the same result.

Comment: @Oskar You anotate them the same way you did with those other strings below: `Text="Version is not following the correct format: $(VersionRegex)"` One point of regex is that it is a matching rule, stored in a plain old string. As such it should be as close to "universally communicateable" as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your original example, you should be able to put the content of the `VersionRegex` property within `CDATA`:

```xml
<Target Name="ValidateVersion" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionRegex><![CDATA[^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,6}(-(beta|rc)(\d{1,1})?)?$]]></VersionRegex>
    <VersionTest>1.2.3</VersionTest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Error
    Text="Version is not following the correct format: $(VersionRegex)"
    Condition="!$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(VersionTest)', '$(VersionRegex)'))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working! Can you add a `!` to the beginning of `Condition`? I will mark your answer as accepted after that.

Comment: Funnily enough, I'll likely be using your answer as I'm trying to use named match groups, but MSBuild wont let me access `$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(VersionTest), $(VersionRegex)).Groups["my_group"]`

Comment: Great that my answer still can be useful to others!

Answer (score 3):

## Workaround

I haven't found the actual issue but a workaround is, as [@Viet Hoang mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095328/regex-that-is-working-in-c-sharp-is-not-working-in-msbuild#comment104424405_59095328), to use CDATA:

`Targets/ValidateVersioning.targets`:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="ValidateVersion"
    TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Version ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
<![CDATA[
if (!Regex.Match(Version, @"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,6}(-(beta|rc)(\d{1,1})?)?$").Success)
{
    Log.LogError("Version has wrong format: {0}", Version);
    return false;
}
]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

`default.props`:

```xml
<Project>

...

  <Import Project="Targets\ValidateVersioning.targets" />
  <Target Condition="$(VERSION) != ''" Name="ValidateVersion" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ValidateVersion Version="$(VERSION)" />
  </Target>

...

</Project>
```

`> dotnet build --no-restore -p:Version=1.3.4` will work but

`> dotnet build --no-restore -p:Version=1.3` will not build